# Firestore data queried with where() does not update in real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

My issue is a very simple one. I am querying data a collection from firestore using the where clause. The data loads only when i hit save in my code but not initially.

My code:

```
db.collection('projects').where('projectid','in',shareids).onSnapshot(query => {
  let projects = []
  query.forEach(doc => {
    projects.push(doc.data()) 
  })   
  console.log(projects) //shows in console after editing my code (just add a space or anythign that changes the file - but does not display initially)   
})
```

What is strange is that when querying the collection using doc() instead of where, this issue does not happen and the firestore data loads in real-time.

This code (loads in realtime):

```
db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).onSnapshot(doc => {
  const userlist = doc.data()
  console.log(userlist)
})
```

Is the issue with firestore or my code?

(Replacing onSnapshot() with .get().then() doesn't work either)

Answer (score 1):

Could there be a problem with the shareids array?

What if you try `.where('projectid','==','aSpecificId')`?

Maybe that will show you if the problem is with the `.where` or with using `in` and your `shareids` array.

Since the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) says:

> Use the `in` operator to combine up to 10 equality (`==`) clauses on the same field with a logical `OR`. An `in` query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values.

For example:

```
citiesRef.where('country', 'in', ['USA', 'Japan']);
```